# How do I propagate the user permission for a website that I have created in the security wizard?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

Sorry for the newbie question, but I can't seem to figure this out.  I have been basically following this example from Microsoft on how to create a web site with logins:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx

I did deviate from the example some in that I went ahead and created roles (Admin, user). I created a folder called "Admin" and inside there is a web page. I configured the Security wizard to Deny access to that page for Anonymous, User, and All Users. When I run the page in Visual Studio it will not let me see the page unless I log in, but once I log in I can see the page. When I publish the web site and try it from another computer (or even the local one for that matter) it will let me see the page without logging in.

I am certain I have no idea how to correctly publish the database. When I first published the page the login that I created in the security wizard was not valid, so I copied the aspnetdb into the App_Config folder in my application directory and it would now let me log in, but it does not seem to be holding the access rules that I have set. I'm pretty certain that I am not publishing correctly but I've been unable to figure out what the correct way to move the settings over is when publishing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer apparently it is considered a bug is VS (maybe maybe not)...

but the answer can be found here

http://www.tino.nl/index.php/2008/06/17/publishing-an-aspnet-site-that-uses-membership-components/

Answer (score 0):

The access rules are NOT in your database but in the web.config. Perhaps your web.config is not correctly deployed with the app.

You can edit the Deny/Access rules in the web.config using the location element ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.100).aspx ) for the folders or individual pages:

```
<configuration>
   <location path="Logon.aspx">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

So you need to make sure the rules at your local machine are also in the web.config on the server.This is not done automatically.